# Use jquery to cache images in indexeddb for offline use

Tags: php, jquery, indexeddb

I have an image-heavy web page that needs to be viewable offline on mobile devices.

I found a [jquery plugin/tutorial](http://dumitruglavan.com/jquery-image-cache-plugin-cache-images-in-browsers-local-storage/) do store images in local storage, but that won't work for my purposes.

Is this something that can easily be adapted to use indexeddb instead?

Also, my images will be updated periodically. Is there a way I can automatically clear the cached versions after a certain amount of time, and force the user to re-load from the web?

Comment: You could also look into the cache manifest features in html5 as an alternative

Comment: I'm using a cache manifest for the html & site UI images, but the images in the main content will exceed the limits allowed with a cache manifest, so I'm trying to use Indexeddb instead.

Answer (score 1):

**IndexedDB**
You can store images into an IndexedDB, but you would be responsible for saving them, clearing them and updating them as needed.

Also if you need it to work on mobile devices, an IndexedDB is not what you want, as none of the current mobile browsers support IndexedDB.  (Source: http://caniuse.com/#feat=indexeddb)

**Offline Applications**
I would recommend instead that you use a new HTML5 feature called Application Cache.  This is supported by almost all the browsers out there (Source: http://caniuse.com/#feat=offline-apps)

To use it you just need to create a Website.manifest file such as:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# v0.0.3 2011-12-21
images/ImageThatIWantToCache.png
images/SecondImage.png
```

Then in your web page alter the html tag to be something like:

```
<html manifest="Website.manifest">
```

Advantages:
1. The browser will automatically cache the images 
2. You access the images using the original URL (i.e. /images/SecondImage.png)
3. Updating is much easier, you just drop the new images onto the web server and update the version number in the manifest file.

You can read more about the [Offline spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/offline.html), or just do a google search for examples.

Comment: The reason I'm not just using Application Cache is the size limit. There will be a lot of images, which will exceed the 5mb limit. I was told that android supported Indexeddb. Is there another option, without the size limitations of Application Cache?

Comment: I don't believe so, it seems like all the browsers are locked at 5MBs.  I think you are going to run into similar problems with IndexedDB.  I believe those are size locked on some browsers.